# directive after dom manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

Imagine a scenario when a dom manipulation is required after directive has been init.
For instance you have jQuery plugin that is wrapped:

```
$().whatever({
  onOpen: function(e) {}
});
```

If we expose and bind that `onOpen` callback we are obliged by angular convention to expose that part for model manipulation.

So we have the problem of waiting for execution DOM code when our element is opened and yet we can not expose that callback for such purposes.

How is that handled gracefully in angular because creating another directive for such purposes seems to me too complicated for such simple problem.
Is there such pattern?

Thank you for your time

Comment: What is your particular  scenario? something like $(...).animate(..., function() {}) ? whats then problem of putting this function to directive attribute?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov The problem is I can use that attribute only for the `controller` and the `model` and not for DOM manipulation. As you know DOM manipulation in controller is considered anti pattern in angular.

Comment: In theory you should have directives for all external libraries code you have like jquery sortable, jquery slider, ckeditor, etc. So there should be no jquery in controllers.

Comment: Not clear at all what problem is. Explanation is far too vague. No idea what `expose that part for model manipulation` means. Please update question with a more detailed problem description and overview of what your directive needs to do

Comment: @charlietfl how are you going to implement that code into directive ? `$().whatever({
  callback: function(e) {$('#element').remove()}
});` where element is yet unknown on directive initialization and what element is depends on something ?

Comment: directive `link` funcion gives you the element as jQuery object for element directive is set on. just do `element.whatever()` and `element.find()` in callback. Show better code example of what it is you are trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl You don't get I am not talking about directive definition and not about particular problem but about structural problem. 
Let's say that in your controller `moo==4` and when that happens you want to execute DOM manipulation but not soemthing predefined in the directive `link` but now on the moment based on the result `moo=4`
In angular you can predefine dom manipultion via directives but you can't manupulate DOM based on model changes in your controller on the move.

Comment: The controller shouldn't know anything about the DOM, that's not it's job. There should never be any dom code in a controller. As far as data binding that's not hard to do and directives are responsible for changing the dom when data changes. There are numerous ways for that to happen also

Comment: @charlietfl yes indeed but model is accessed via controller and that controller can comunicate with the directive only via predifined logic

Comment: Stop being so vague and point out real world situation that you are trying to resolve. Controller can communicate with directive many different ways